# write unit test for web.py application by using pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, web.py

I would like to write unit test for web.py application by using pytest. How to invoke the web.py services in pytest.

Code:

```
import web

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals()) 

class index:
    def GET(self):
        return "Hello, world!"

if __name__ == "__main__":    
 app.run()
```

It can be done by using python requests module, when we run the web.py services, it will run http://localhost:8080/. Then import requests module and use get method and in response object, you can verify the result. That's fine.

By using Paste and nose also we can achieve this as per web.py official documentation. http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial.

Is there any solution in pytest like option in paste and nose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Actually the code from the web.py recipe [Testing with Paste and Nose](http://webpy.org/cookbook/testing_with_paste_and_nose) could be used with py.test almost as is, just removing the `nose.tools` import and updating assertions appropriately.

But if you want to know how to write tests for web.py applications in the py.test style, they could look like this:

```py
from paste.fixture import TestApp

# I assume the code from the question is saved in a file named app.py,
# in the same directory as the tests. From this file I'm importing the variable 'app'
from app import app

def test_index():
    middleware = []
    test_app = TestApp(app.wsgifunc(*middleware))
    r = test_app.get('/')
    assert r.status == 200
    assert 'Hello, world!' in r
```

As you will add further tests, you will probably refactor creation of the test app out to a fixture:

```py
from pytest import fixture # added
from paste.fixture import TestApp
from app import app

def test_index(test_app):
    r = test_app.get('/')
    assert r.status == 200
    assert 'Hello, world!' in r

@fixture()
def test_app():
    middleware = []
    return TestApp(app.wsgifunc(*middleware))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply  and will try this solution and let you know result